# Laravel query builder group into nested arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am using Laravel with query builder in my project.

I have the following table:

```
Table: worker_tasks
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| id     | worker_id | task_id    | started_at          |
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| 227350 |     50765 |       2399 | 2021-12-02 12:24:38 |
| 227351 |     50765 |       1377 | 2021-12-12 09:34:22 |
| 227352 |     84245 |       2294 | 2021-12-07 10:37:11 |
+--------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

And I wish to retrieve data into an array of nested arrays, with `worker_id` as key of each one.
In this case, expected result will be:

```
[
    50765 => [
        {
          "task_id": 2399,
          "started_at": "2021-12-02 12:24:38",
        },
        {
          "task_id": 1377,
          "started_at": "2021-12-12 09:34:22",
        },
    ],
    84245 => [
        {
          "task_id": 2294,
          "started_at": "2021-12-07 10:37:11",
        },
    ],
]
```

I tried to use the [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-keyby) collection method, but it takes only one element for each key, as written in documentation:

> If multiple items have the same key, only the last one will appear in the new collection

I wonder whether there is a straight way to do it (using some built-in Laravel method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GroupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-groupby) method instead of `keyBy`

Comment: Just to make it clear, the call to `groupBy()` must be done **after** the `get()` call: `$query->get()->groupBy(['worker_id'])`.